# Library for sending emails in .net

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Is there any good library for sending mails in c#? something like actionmailer in rails. I know the .net framework has some classes but I'm looking for something like a wrapper that fits specific scenarios hopefully saving me some time.

Comment: What specific scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx)

> The MailDefinition class can be used
>   by controls to create a MailMessage
>   object from a text file or a string
>   that contains the body of the e-mail
>   message. Use the MailDefinition class
>   to simplify creating predefined e-mail
>   messages to be sent by a control. If
>   you want to send e-mail not using a
>   control, see the System.Net.Mail
>   class.
>
> You can make text substitutions in the
>   body of the e-mail message by passing
>   to the CreateMailMessage method an
>   IDictionary instance that maps strings
>   to their replacements.
>
> The MailMessage object created by the
>   MailDefinition class is sent using the
>   Send method of the SmtpClient class.
>   To be able to send e-mail, you must
>   configure an SMTP mail server in your
>   Web.config file. For more information,
>   see the  Element (Network
>   Settings).

Doesn't support databinding, just text replacement.

Answer (score 4):

The `System.Net.Mail` namespace has all you need, really.

Check out the [MSDN docs on System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and check out [this site dedicated](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) to that namespace.

You get classes like `MailMessage`, `MailAddress`, `SmtpClient` and a lot more - really all you need - no need for other, third-party libraries, really.

How you create the message body - whatever templating you want to use to do so - is totally up to you. This shouldn't be part of the mail-sending facility - it just sends mails (that's its single responsibility). How to create the mail body is a different responsibility, handled by some other classes - you're totally free what to use there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the .NET Framework does not come with an SMTP server and so you will need to have access to an SMTP server in order to send any email that you construct using a library or template system. This might not be an issue if you are doing this as part of a company project as your business will not doubt have that ability. As a home project you would need to use the details provided by your ISP so you can send an email.